# Strange error with custom launcher

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to write a launcher for a modpack. But when I try to launch minecraft (using http://pastebin.com/yfiRpVyga) with forge and no mods I get the following http://pastebin.com/5Rt7Eq2q .

Could anyone point me in a new direction that could lead to a conclusion?

I've tried to redownload jar files to make sure that they not broken. Also verified the files as they was taken from the current MultiMC launcher as it is working there.

Comment: StackOverflow questions should include code, not links to code.

Answer (score 0):

> 2013-10-24 23:15:43 [SEVERE] [ForgeModLoader] There is a binary
>   discrepency between the expected input class aa (aa) and the actual
>   class. Checksum on disk is 7 c7533d5, in patch c7e1682c. Things are
>   probably about to go very wrong. Did you put something into the jar
>   file?

Try it without modifying forge maybe? The class aa looks like its throwing the error.

You might want to try using MCP or some other deobfuscation.

Comment: Haven't modified anything, seemed like i got it fixed redownloading everything and regenerating the configs. So it seemed to been a corrupted jar file somehow.